# How to set up a job that picks up a dynamically-named artifact

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and CI. I'm trying to set up a job that picks up an artifact (.apk file)from a different project and uses it as the apk for my parameterized job.(mobile automation)

Problem is that the name of the apk changes everytime with a few variables. So i need to be able to pick this apk and trigger my job.

With what I've set up, i get a null pointer exception for my build even though the build gets copied into workspace.

Could anyone please direct me.

Comment: @isherwood thank you very much. I'll try these as well. To be clearer, job A triggers job B. Job A artifact (apk file) is a parameter for Job B. Since, i have just been exploring since yesterday, one option I'm also thinking of, is if i could pass the build number as the parameter to job B after job A runs successfully. I can play with this information to build the Jenkins url which would then direct me to the apk file itself. Any information would be very useful. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

1. You first need to archive artifacts before you can copy them . Its a post-build action. To specify your apk you can use the wildcard *.apk there, check [Archive the artifacts in hudson/jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins)
2. You need to allow other projects to copy over your artifacts, check "Permission to copy artifacts" https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin
3. In the job you want to use those artifacts, specify the build step "Copy artifacts from another project"

---

Edit: Maybe i misunderstood your question, if you have the artifacts already copied into your workspace, either rename it with a wildcard, i.e. `mv *.apk staticname.apk`.

Or add a shell script that saves the name of your apk into a parameter, which you then can reference in your tests. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17859391/3623345) for how to set and publish variables.